# How can I make a transparant SurfaceView with native EGL?

Tags: android, android-ndk, surfaceview, egl

I want to overlay a drawer on a camera SurfaceView， Like this：

```
UI Layer(RGBA)
--------
Drawer Layer(RGBA\GLES)
--------
Camera Layer
```

Now, I can not make Drawer layer tranparant.

### 1. Set SurfaceView to top. And set format to RGBA_8888/TRANSLUCENT/TRANSPARENT and chooseConfig with EGL_ALPHA_SIZE.

```
setZOrderOnTop(true); //try setZOrderMediaOverlay, too.
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

And choose config with EGL_ALPHA_SIZE.

```
const EGLint attribs[] = {EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                          EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                          EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                          EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                          EGL_NONE
};
//...
glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
```

I got a black backgound. Camera layer was not showed.

### 2. Base on *1*， Add {EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE,  EGL_TRANSPARENT_RGB} to the eglconfig

```
const EGLint attribs[] = {EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                          EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                          EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE,  EGL_TRANSPARENT_RGB,
                          EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                          EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                          EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                          EGL_NONE
};
//...
glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
```

EGL Init failed in chooseConfig.
Then I print all egl configs, not one has a { EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE, EGL_TRANSPARENT_RGB }.

I has solved it. Just change glClearColor to

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Seems Alpha channel in GL framebuffer was igonred. May be Android use ADD not ONE_MINUS_SRC to blend Windows? Can someone explain it clearly?